# Common TOC in all pages of ASCIIDOC collection

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a collection of ASCIIDOC files. I want to have a common TOC that lists all pages.
For example, if I have the following files

- file1.adoc
- file11.adoc
- file111.adoc
- file12.adoc
- file121.adoc
- file1211.adoc
- file2.adoc
- file21.adoc

I want to show a TOC like this on all of the above pages,

- file 1

  - file 11

    - file 111
  - file 12

    - file 121

      - file 1211
- file 2

  - file 21

Is it possible to do that?

I've tried to have a master.adoc file which has links to all these files. But I'm not sure how to include that on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that you cannot do that using Asciidoc alone. So I wrote a preprocessor to Asciidoc (https://github.com/verhas/jamal) that adds macros; that way, you can list files using the `listDir` macro. You can also format the list output, though I do not think creating a hierarchy based on the file names is possible or easy.

Using that preprocessor you edit `*.adoc.jam` files. If you use IntelliJ you get the WYSIWYG editing, and the `.adoc` file is contrinously created and saved updated with the actual files. The TOC part of the macro enhanced Asciidoc file can be

```
= List of all documents in the current directory

{%@listDir (format="* <<$name,$simpleName>>" sep="\n" pattern=".*\\.adoc$" maxDepth=1) . %}
```

and you can see the screen capture how it looks in IntelliJ.

[image: IntelliJ Jamal WYSIWYG editing]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. I have decided to use Antora. It has the navigation feature using nav.adoc